# The multi-part identifier "Address.Telephone" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I'm a new user and have received some great help today, hopefully this will be my last post regarding this issue!

Error - Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
        The multi-part identifier "Address.Telephone" could not be bound.

```
SELECT * FROM [User]
INNER JOIN "Order" ON [User].ID = [Order].UserId
WHERE LEN([Address]​​.[Telephone]) = 10 AND "Order".[Status] = 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be nice if you interacted a bit more. For example, on your last question, which was tagged [tag:mysql] but looked (as here) like SQL Server, you were *asked* which database system this actually was for, but you never responded. Any chance of a response this time?

Comment: Where is the Address table in your join?

Comment: Hi Damien apology's its for SQL Server - I'll correct the tags now

Comment: You have used `[Address]​​.[Telephone]` but table `[Address]​​` has not been joined in your query anywhere, maybe its a typo or you need to add this table into your joins.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers - i'm still working over the issue and will update when solved. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which table The column Telephone comes from, but as long as its not duplicated across tables you can remove the Table it comes from ie. from "Address.Telephone" to "Telephone". If this is still erroring, the tables you are joining together (User\Order) dont have the Telephone column and therefore you need to join in another table that has the Telephone column!

1) Telephone is in the User or Order Table

```
SELECT * 
FROM [User]
INNER JOIN "Order" ON [User].ID = [Order].UserId
WHERE LEN([Telephone]) = 10 AND "Order".[Status] = 3
```

or

2) You know Telephone is in the User Table

```
SELECT * 
FROM [User]
INNER JOIN "Order" ON [User].ID = [Order].UserId
WHERE LEN([User].[Telephone]) = 10 AND "Order".[Status] = 3
```

or

3) Telephone is in a totally different table

```
SELECT * 
FROM [User]
INNER JOIN "Order" ON [User].ID = [Order].UserId
INNER JOIN UserDetails ON  UserDetails.UserID = User.UserId
WHERE LEN(UserDetails.[Telephone]) = 10 AND "Order".[Status] = 3
```